# Combine 2 Excel tables into one appending the data?

Tags: excel, append

I have 2 tables on 2 separate sheets of an MS Excel 2007 workbook, like below:

```
===========================
no.   f_name     l_name  
===========================
13   Little     Timmy
1   John       Doe
17   Baby       Jessica
---------------------------


===========================
no.   f_name     l_name  
===========================
1   john       Tim
16   kyle       joe
14   Baby       katy
22   qbcd       wsde
---------------------------
```

Both have the same columns, but they can have different data.

I want to combine the data of both tables vertically i.e. a single table with all the data in a 3rd separate sheet.
If possible, I want to add another column with the sheet name from where the row came.

```
===================================
SheetName   no.   f_name     l_name  
===================================
Sheet1      13   Little     Timmy
Sheet1      1   John       Doe
Sheet1      17   Baby       Jessica
Sheet2      1   john       Tim
Sheet2      16   kyle       joe
Sheet2      14   Baby       katy
Sheet2      22   qbcd       wsde
-----------------------------------
```

Can it be done without using macros?

Answer (score 11):

> This answer deals with [Structured Tables](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Using-structured-references-with-Excel-tables-F5ED2452-2337-4F71-BED3-C8AE6D2B276E) as interpreted by Excel. While the methods could easily be transcribed to raw data matrixes without assigned table structure, the formulas and VBA coding for this solution will be targeted at true structured tables.

### Preamble

A third table can maintain the combined data of two tables with some native worksheet formulas but keeping the third table sized correctly as rows are added or deleted to/from the dependent tables will require either manual resizing operations or some VBA that tracks these changes and conforms the third table to suit. I've included options to add both the source table's worksheet name as well as some table maintenance VBA code at the end of this answer.

> If all you want is an operational example workbook without all the explanation, skip to the end of this answer for a link to the workbook used to create this procedure.

### Sample data tables

[image: Table Collection Sample Data]

I've used the OP's sample data to construct two tables named (by default) Table1 and Table2 on worksheets Sheet1 and Sheet2 respectively. I've intentionally offset them by varying degrees from each worksheet's A1 cell in order to demonstrate a structured table's ability to address either itself or another structured table in a formula as a separate entity regardless of its position on the parent worksheet. The third table will be constructed in a similar manner. These offsets are for demonstration purposes only; they are not required.

### Step 1: Build the third table

Build the headers for the third table and select that future header row and at least one row below it to base the Insert ► Tables ► Table command upon.

[image: Combining Tables New Table]

Your new empty third table on the Sheet3 worksheet should resemble the following.

[image: Collecting Table Data Build New Table]

### Step 2: Populate the third table

Start by populating the first cell in the third table's [DataBodyRange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa214261(v=office.11).aspx). In this example, that would be Sheet3!C6. Type or paste the following formula in C6 keeping in mind that it is based on the default table names. If you have changed your tables names, adjust accordingly.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Table1, ROW([@[no.]])-ROW(Table3[#Headers]),COLUMN(A:A)), INDEX(Table2, ROW([@[no.]])-ROW(Table3[#Headers])-ROWS(Table1),COLUMN(A:A)))
```

The [INDEX function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-0ee99cef-a811-4762-8cfb-a222dd31368a) first retrieves each available row from **Table1**. The actual row numbers are derived with the [ROW function](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/ROW-function-3A63B74A-C4D0-4093-B49A-E76EB49A6D8D) referencing defined pieces of the structured table together with a little maths. When Table1 runs out of rows, retrieval is passed to a second INDEX function referencing **Table2** by the [IFERROR function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IFERROR-function-F59BACDC-78BD-4924-91DF-A869D0B08CD5) and its sequential rows are retrieved with the ROW and [ROWS functions](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/ROWS-function-B592593E-3FC2-47F2-BEC1-BDA493811597) using a bit more maths. The [COLUMN function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COLUMN-function-44E8C754-711C-4DF3-9DA4-47A55042554B) is used as `COLUMN(A:A)` which is going to retrieve the first column of the referenced table regardless of where it is on the worksheet. This will progress to the second, third, etc. column as the formula is filled right.

Speaking of filling right, fill the formula right to E6. You should have something that approximates the following.

[image: Aggregating table data, third table]

### Step 2.5: [optional] Add the source table's parent worksheet name

Grab Table3's sizing handle (indicated by the orange arrow in the sample image below) in the lower right hand corner and drag it right one column to add a new column to the table. Rename the header label to something more appropriate than the default. I've used **Sheet** as a column label.

[image: Collating table data - source worksheet name]

While you cannot retrieve the worksheet name of the source table directly, the [CELL function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/CELL-function-51BD39A5-F338-4DBE-A33F-955D67C2B2CF) can retrieve the fully qualified path, filename and worksheet of any cell in a saved workbook¹ as one of its optional *info_types*.

Put the following formula into Table3's empty cell in the first row of the new column you have just created.

```
=TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(CELL("filename", IF((ROW([@[no.]])-ROW(Table3[#Headers]))>ROWS(Table1), Table2, Table1)), CHAR(93), REPT(CHAR(32), 999)), 255))
```

**Complate populating Table3**

If you are not planning on finishing this small project with some VBA to maintain Table3's dimensions when rows are added or deleted from either of the two source tables then simply grab Table3's resizing handle and drag down until you have accumulated all of the data from both tables. See the bottom of this answer for a sample image of the expected results.

If you are planning to add some VBA, then skip the full population of Table3 and move on to the next step.

### Step 3: Add some VBA to maintain the third table

Full automation of a process that is triggered by changes to a worksheet's data is best handled by the worksheet's [Worksheet_Change](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839775.aspx) event macro. Since there are three tables involved, each on their own worksheet, the [Workbook_SheetChange event macro](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196611.aspx) is a better method of handling the change events from multiple worksheets.

Open the VBE with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>. Once you have it open, look for the **Project Explorer** in the upper left. If it is not visible, then tap <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to open it. Locate **ThisWorkbook** and right-click then choose View Code (or just double-click ThisWorkbook).

[image: Collect data from multiple tables]

Paste the following into the new pane titled something like *Book1 - ThisWorkbook (Code)*.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    Select Case Sh.Name
        Case Sheet1.Name
            If Not Intersect(Target, Sheet1.ListObjects("Table1").Range.Offset(1, 0)) Is Nothing Then
                On Error GoTo bm_Safe_Exit
                Application.EnableEvents = False
                Call update_Table3
            End If
        Case Sheet2.Name
            If Not Intersect(Target, Sheet2.ListObjects("Table2").Range.Offset(1, 0)) Is Nothing Then
                On Error GoTo bm_Safe_Exit
                Application.EnableEvents = False
                Call update_Table3
            End If
    End Select

bm_Safe_Exit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub

Private Sub update_Table3()
    Dim iTBL3rws As Long, rng As Range, rngOLDBDY As Range
    iTBL3rws = Sheet1.ListObjects("Table1").DataBodyRange.Rows.Count
    iTBL3rws = iTBL3rws + Sheet2.ListObjects("Table2").DataBodyRange.Rows.Count
    iTBL3rws = iTBL3rws + Sheet3.ListObjects("Table3").DataBodyRange.Cells(1, 1).Row - _
                          Sheet3.ListObjects("Table3").Range.Cells(1, 1).Row
    With Sheet3.ListObjects("Table3")
        Set rngOLDBDY = .DataBodyRange
        .Resize .Range.Cells(1, 1).Resize(iTBL3rws, .DataBodyRange.Columns.Count)
        If rngOLDBDY.Rows.Count > .DataBodyRange.Rows.Count Then
            For Each rng In rngOLDBDY
                If Intersect(rng, .DataBodyRange) Is Nothing Then
                    rng.Clear
                End If
            Next rng
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

These two routines make extensive use of the Worksheet [.CodeName property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837552.aspx). A worksheet's **CodeName** is *Sheet1, Sheet2, Sheet3, etc* and does not change when a worksheet is renamed. In fact, they are rarely changed by even the more advanced user. They have been used so that you can rename your worksheets without having to modify the code. However, they should be pointing to the correct worksheets now. Modify the code if your tables and worksheets are not the same as given. You can see the individual worksheet codenames in brackets beside their worksheet [.Name property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa175750(v=office.11).aspx) in the above image showing the VBE's Project Explorer.

Tap <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> to return to your worksheets. All that is left would be to finish populating **Table3** by selecting any cell in **Table1** or **Table2** and pretending to modify it by tapping <kbd>F2</kbd> then <kbd>Enter↵</kbd>. Your results should resemble the following.

[image: Combine two tables into one automatically]

If you have followed along all the way to here then you should have a pretty comprehensive collection table that actively combines the data from two source 'child' tables. If you added the VBA as well then maintenance of the third collection table is virtually non-existent.

### Renaming the tables

If you choose to rename any or all of the three tables, the worksheet formulas will instantly and automatically reflect the changes. If you have opted to include the Workbook_SheetChange and accompanying helper sub procedure, you will have to go back into the ThisWorkbook code sheet and use Find & Replace to make the appropriate changes.

**Sample Workbook**

I've made the fully operational example workbook available from my public DropBox.

[Table_Collection_w_Sheetname.xlsb](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QOajDioexr82m2DdRaUkzWO7d6qv0Y0s/view?usp=sharing)

---

¹ <sub>The [CELL function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/CELL-function-51BD39A5-F338-4DBE-A33F-955D67C2B2CF) can only retrieve the worksheet name of a saved workbook. If a workbook has not been saved then it has no filename and the CELL function will return an empty string when asked for the filename.</sub>

Comment: This is a great write up and works. How would I go about adding a third table to be appended though?

Comment: great write up. easy solution to common problem.

Comment: Great answer! Nice comprehensive write up as well on how the solution works.

Comment: @Jeeped : your answer is awesome and comes with great detail. The sample file doesn't seem to be available anymore. Could you share it again?

Comment: @AntoineDriard, I reproduced the workbook and stuck a copy on google drive. I've updated the link in the response above.

Answer (score 4):

You can activate the *Office Clipboard* (arrow at bottom right of clipboard section on Ribbon Home Tab). Copy both ranges then use the **Paste All** command as shown below.

You would still need to fill down the sheet name in an extra column first though which can be done by double-clicking the fill handle.

[image]

**Update**

To get the same results with formulas try filling down this for the sheet name:

```
=IF(ROW()<=COUNTA(Sheet1!A:A),"Sheet1",IF(ROW()<COUNTA(Sheet1:Sheet2!A:A),"Sheet2",""))
```

and then fill down and across this formula for the values in the tables:

```
=IF(ROW()<=COUNTA(Sheet1!A:A),Sheet1!A2,IF(ROW()<COUNTA(Sheet1:Sheet2!A:A),INDEX(Sheet2!A:A,ROW()-COUNTA(Sheet1!A:A)+1),""))
```

Comment: Thanks!! Yea.. that's an option but the thing is I also want the final table to automatically update itself when I make changes in any of the input tables...
I don't know if I can use any function here. I have been searching for it for a while now but couldn't find anything. Maybe macro is the only option here :(

Comment: You could use the paste-special `Paste Link` command to link the combined table to the source table. This would update automatically with changes in the original table provided the number of items in the lists doesn't change

Comment: I improved on @lori_m's answer to make it more tolerant of inserting a row on the source sheets: `=IF(ROW()<(COUNTA(Sheet1!A:A)+1),INDEX(Sheet1!A:A,ROW()),IF(ROW()<COUNTA(Sheet1:Sheet2!A:A),INDEX(Sheet2!A:A,ROW()-COUNTA(Sheet1!A:A)+1),"")`

Answer (score 2):

lori_m made a really good contribution that I built upon by using Microsoft Excel Tables and structured references.

First make a column in your output table called RowID which contains the row number within the table and then use this to fill the data values.

```
=IF( INDIRECT("Table3[RowId]")<=ROWS(Table1)
    ,INDEX(Table1[column1],INDIRECT("Table3[RowId]"))
    ,INDEX(Table2[Column1],INDIRECT("Table3[RowId]")-ROWS(Table1)))
```

There is a [detailed explanation of how this works on my blog](http://blog.jamesbayley.com/2013/03/14/create-the-union-of-two-tables-in-excel/) as it was too long to include here.

Answer (score 1):

A slight modification to Jeeped's code.

If you happen to use a similar approach, but with several tables (e.g. more than 10), then it will be rather cumbersome to attempt to manually add every name of every table. This is also a problem if you change names of the tables, since the names are hard-wired in VBA. To avoid additional work, consider this:

So, assume the following:

- On each worksheet there is one or several tables, but they have similar structure.
- There are only tables on worksheets - no other members of ListObjects collection are being present.
- Every time we edit a table on a sheet, this will trigger an update in master table (table 3).

Then the **Workbook_SheetChange** Sub in the example above could look like the following:

```
     Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
     Dim tbl As ListObject
     For Each tbl In ActiveSheet.ListObjects
        If Not Intersect(Target, tbl.Range.Offset(1, 0)) Is Nothing Then
            On Error GoTo bm_Safe_Exit
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            Call update_Table
        End If
        Next tbl
        bm_Safe_Exit:
        Application.EnableEvents = True
     End Sub
```

Edit. The second routine will then look like:

```
   Private Sub update_Table()
    Dim iTBL3rws As Long, rng As Range, rngOLDBDY As Range
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    iTBL3rws = 0

    ' consider all tables, excluding master table
    For Each sht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        For Each tbl In sht.ListObjects
            If tbl.Name <> "Table3" Then
                iTBL3rws = iTBL3rws + tbl.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count
            End If
        Next tbl
    Next sht

    iTBL3rws = iTBL3rws + Sheet3.ListObjects("Table3").DataBodyRange.Cells(1, 1).Row - Sheet3.ListObjects("Table3").Range.Cells(1, 1).Row
        With Sheet3.ListObjects("Table3")

            Set rngOLDBDY = .DataBodyRange

            .Resize .Range.Cells(1, 1).Resize(iTBL3rws, .DataBodyRange.Columns.Count)

            If rngOLDBDY.Rows.Count > .DataBodyRange.Rows.Count Then
                For Each rng In rngOLDBDY
                    If Intersect(rng, .DataBodyRange) Is Nothing Then
                        rng.Clear
                    End If
                Next rng
            End If
        End With

End Sub
```

This routine differs from previous one by eliminating preprogrammed cases. When there is a change registered on active worksheet, then any table in this worksheet which is about to be changed will trigger **update_Table** procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Im using this code/formula. works well for my needs only thing i would like to know is how do i make a better cell formula so i can use 3+ tables as a reference. currently im just nesting a bunch of iferror statements within the iferror

```html
=IFERROR(INDEX(Table1, ROW([@Date])-ROW(Table3[#Headers]),COLUMN(A:A)),IFERROR( INDEX(Table2, ROW([@Date])-ROW(Table3[#Headers])-ROWS(Table1),COLUMN(A:A)), IFERROR(INDEX(Table4, ROW([@Date])-ROW(Table3[#Headers])-ROWS(Table2)-ROWS(Table1),COLUMN(A:A)),INDEX(Table5, ROW([@Date])-ROW(Table3[#Headers])-ROWS(Table2)-ROWS(Table1)-ROWS(Table4),COLUMN(A:A)))))
```

Im also using the