# Modify table size dynamically

Tags: excel, vba

I wrote a code that import a table from an other sheet after filtering some lines.My problem is that when I exceed the number of lines of the table that I have in this sheet it exceeds the table. Now, I want to know if there is a way to modify the size of the table dynamically with the number of lines.

```
Public Sub refresh()

Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, lr1 As Long, lRow As Long
    Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Scénarios de menace")
    Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Analyse de risque")
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    ws2.Range("B6:N" & ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row).ClearContents 
    lr1 = ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
        ws1.Range("A1:A" & lr1).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="x"
        ws1.Range("B3:N" & lr1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
        ws2.Range("B6").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
        ws1.Range("A6:A" & lr1).AutoFilter
        ws2.Activate: ws2.Cells(1, 1).Activate
End Sub
```

Comment: Have a look at the `update_Table3` companion sub procedure in [Combine 2 Excel tables into one appending the data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9923385/combine-2-excel-tables-into-one-appending-the-data/32680703#32680703). Not only will it expand a table to new rows but also remove `#VALUE!` errors left over from a shrinking table's formulas.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that, to resize a table it is easier when you know it's name.

I've added a 3 lines to your code :

1. To get the total range used by pasted data
2. To create a table for that total range
3. To resize the table (not really useful here as the table was just set)

   ```
   Public Sub refresh()

   Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, lr1 As Long, lRow As Long, ResultsRange As String
       Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Scénarios de menace")
       Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Analyse de risque")
       Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
       ws2.Range("B6:N" & ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row).ClearContents
       lr1 = ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

       ws1.Range("A1:A" & lr1).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="x"
       ws1.Range("B3:N" & lr1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
       ws2.Range("B6").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
       ws1.Range("A6:A" & lr1).AutoFilter
       ws2.Activate
       ws2.Cells(1, 1).Activate

       ResultsRange = "$B$6:$N$" & ws2.Range("B"& ws2.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
       ws2.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range(ResultsRange), , xlYes).Name = "Results_Table"
       ws2.ListObjects("Results_Table").Resize Range(ResultsRange)

   End Sub
   ```

Comment: Thank you both for your answer.

Comment: On which line? Did you understand the principle of the creation and resizing the table?

Comment: Yes, I understand. I added those lines in the code :

Comment: Yes, I added those lines ion the code but it gives me an error about the Range : " error 9 susbscript is out of Range" 
ws2.Range("B6:N" & ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Name = "Table1"
    ws2.ListObjects("Table1").Resize Range("B6:N" & ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)

Comment: `Cells(ws2.Rows.Count).` you forgot the column there, it should be `Cells(ws2.Rows.Count,"A")` or whatever column you want to look at

Comment: Mkay... but c'mon, how do you want us (at least me) to be able to help you with so little to work on... Post your code in an edit of your post and try to describe the issue more accurately...