# Combine multiple sheets to 1 sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

Is there any way to combine 2 or more sheets to 1 sheet without using VBA?

I was thinking of having a unique value in the first column, then VLOOKUP for the rest. but i'm having a hard time figuring out how to return to the first cell in the 2nd sheet.

[image]

Comment: You could just copy and paste them manually and then go to the `Data`-Ribbon and use `Remove Duplicates`.

Comment: This can also be done with structured (ListObject) tables but a small amount of VBA is necessary to resize the aggregate table if rows are added/deleted from either of the source tables. ([Combine 2 Excel tables into one appending the data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9923385/combine-2-excel-tables-into-one-appending-the-data))

Comment: i would like to automate it like if i add data in sheet 1 or sheet 2, it would automatically appear in sheet 3, more like a summary of all sheets.

Answer (score 0):

Using your sample data image (it's important that numbers remain numbers in column A), these two standard formulas are destined for Sheet3!A2:B2.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!A$2:INDEX(Sheet1!A:A, MATCH(1E+99, Sheet1!A:A)), ROW(1:1)), IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!A$2:INDEX(Sheet2!A:A, MATCH(1E+99, Sheet2!A:A)), ROW(1:1)-COUNT(Sheet1!A:A)), ""))
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($A2, Sheet1!$A:B, COLUMN(B:B), FALSE), IFERROR(VLOOKUP($A2, Sheet2!$A:B, COLUMN(B:B), FALSE), ""))
```

Fill B2 right to C2 then fill A2:C2 down far enough to catch all available entries.

You may want to consider a conditional formatting rule used as a warning when there are not enough formulas to cover the entries from Sheet1 and Sheet2. Something like `=COUNT(Sheet1!$A:$A)+COUNT(Sheet2!$A:$A)<>COUNT(Sheet3!$A:$A)` to turn the header red.

There is a formula for retrieving the appropriate source worksheet name to an additional column in [Combine 2 Excel tables into one appending the data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9923385/combine-2-excel-tables-into-one-appending-the-data).

Comment: thanks!! i think this one will work, i just have to vlookup the rest of data, column a would be the one haveing this =IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!A$2:INDEX(Sheet1!A:A, MATCH(1E+99, Sheet1!A:A)), ROW(1:1)), IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!A$2:INDEX(Sheet2!A:A, MATCH(1E+99, Sheet2!A:A)), ROW(1:1)-COUNT(Sheet1!A:A)), ""))

Comment: You will need some version of the second formula I provided for the VLOOKUPs. If the id cannot be found on the first worksheet, it needs to look on the second.

Comment: ok, thank you very much for this formula, it's working for my sample, i'll try to make it full size on my worksheet. :)

Comment: Hi, if i'm gonna add more than 2 sheets, i just need to add an argument iferror on the "value if error" for sheet 4? am i right?

Comment: No. You also have to compensate for the number of entries that already exist. See how I've compensated the ROW(1:1) between the first worksheet and the second with the COUNT from the first.