# Complex linking in excel (dynamically?)

Tags: database, vba, excel

I'm not the best at using spreadsheets but I've given a task and its possible I may be a little out of my depth (I'm more of a web programmer)

I have two sheets:
One called Area A and one called Area B with headings:

Time - Location - Reference

I need to set up a new sheet with these column headings:

Time - Reference - Location - Area

Then make a sortable list (I can do this bit)

The Location A & B sheets will be constantly changing and this will need to be reflected in the new sheet when ever it is opened (maybe some sort of onload style event?)

Any ideas on the easiest way to do the above (or if indeed it is doable)? I don't want to be spoon fed, I'd be happy to be pointed in the right direction or to be given some keywords I can Google (I learn better this way).

Many thanks!

Comment: How does the new sheet access A and B?  Are they publicly available?  On the same computer?  In the same directory?

Comment: Are all of the worksheets in the same workbook?

Comment: You could set it in the click event of the tab control or use formulas if feasible.

Comment: They are currently on two different workbooks but it's possible they could be placed in the same workbook along with the third ( new) worksheet.

Comment: See [Combine 2 Excel tables into one appending the data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9923385/combine-2-excel-tables-into-one-appending-the-data).

Comment: Thanks Jeeped, that's exactly what I'm looking for! Thanks all for your help!

Answer (score 0):

This type of data manipulation is something that excel is not good for and is prone to errors.

The best two good ways to do this.

Manually
On sheet "Area A" add a column with area name I.e. Area A. Do this for each "data" sheet. Then manually or via vba copy and paste one sheet at a time to you're aggregated sheet.

Programmatically using VBA
Loop through each sheet and copy and paste to the aggregated sheet adding a column with the sheet name as you paste.

For either of these methods the important thing to do is build in a few checks on counts at the end to make sure your not missing any data.