# Excel: create a LIVE copy of a table on two different sheets of a workbook

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I was wondering if it is possible to create a LIVE copy of an excel table on another sheet of the same file.
For a LIVE copy of a table I mean something that is updated every time the original table is updated, that is:

- If I change the value of a cell in the original table, the copy is updated
- If insert or delete a row/column in the original table, the same row/column is changed in the copy

I am not able to do something like this: if I copy my table, the copy is not updated when I change the original.
If I link one by one the cells of the table with a second table, then when I add or delete a row the second table is unchanged.
Any idea on how can this be solved?

Comment: You may find [Combine 2 Excel tables into one appending the data?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9923385/combine-2-excel-tables-into-one-appending-the-data) interesting.

Comment: In your "Sheet2", why not just put the cells equal to your main document? IE `=Sheet1!A1`, etc.?

Comment: @BruceWayne, you are right I can do something like this but in this case in "Sheet2" I will have everything is in "Sheet1" and I would prefer to have only the table

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use Macro VBA for this. 
Each time you run codes it will update:

```
Sub UpdateSheets()
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Range("A1:D10").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Sheet2").Select
Range("A1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
End Sub
```

Copy this codes into the VBA module. 
 It can be opened with <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd> and saved. Change the range according to your requirements.