# How to combine records from different tables?

Tags: sql, vba, excel, ado

There are two worksheets in same workbook that have the same structure-same field names.

for example :

Table 1

```
- Officer  name   mkt 
 - s15     peter  15
 - s17     mary   18
 - S32     tom    42
 - S32     tom    89
```

Table 2

```
- Officer  name   mkt 
 - s56     jason  55
 - s31     alex   34
 - S54     gee    45
```

Now I'm using ADO to run the sql in excel-vba.

```
select officer ,name ,sum(mkt) from [$table1]
```

Now I want to combine these 2 tables records and select later.

That means:

Table 3

```
- Officer  name   mkt 
 - s15     peter  15
 - s17     mary   18
 - S32     tom    42
 - S32     tom    89
 - s56     jason  55
 - s31     alex   34
 - S54     gee    45
```

Then later make the selection(SQL) .

```
  select officer ,name ,sum(mkt) from [$table3]
```

**Is it able to perform it in SQL or VBA (i prefer to perform it in SQL Statement )?**

*I prefer to use sth SQL technique to perform it . Something like join table ? But join table only join the columns in different tables.Now I want to join rows *

Comment: i think you need the `JOIN` clause...

Comment: See [Combine 2 Excel tables into one appending the data?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9923385/combine-2-excel-tables-into-one-appending-the-data).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a common table expression to union the tables into one and then perform the aggregate sum. I'm using  `SET NOCOUNT ON;`  because I had issues before in excel if I omitted this. A full outer join between the two tables would also work.

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM [$table1]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT *
    FROM [$table2]
)

SELECT office, name, sum(mkt)
FROM CTE
GROUP BY office, name
```

You can also try without the CTE:

```
SELECT office, name, sum(mkt)
FROM(
    SELECT *
    FROM [$table1]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT *
    FROM [$table2]
)
GROUP BY office, name
```

Comment: it is not a must to create table 3 .But i want to express i hope to get  ` officer ,name ,sum(mkt)` from from both table and show the result in one table .  But is it possible to make it short?

Comment: This approach works. Are you worried the query has got too many characters?

Comment: yes .as my query have to select so many fields .It is so difficult to add `t3.......` on every field name.

Comment: ok, I edited the answer so it doesn't use the t3 alias anymore

Comment: it is not working .`SET NOCOUNT ON;`only apply to SQL Server (starting with 2008),Azure SQL Database,Azure SQL Data Warehouse . `WITH CTE AS(` is not working too . I m using excel-vba with ADO ,but not sql server

Comment: What dbms are you using?

Comment: I have added an answer without CTE

Comment: i dun use database . I just execute sql and paste on excel worksheet

Comment: This simple SQL query would work on a relational database. It seems that there might be limitations to what you can achieve using SQL in excel.

Answer (score 0):

```
    select officer ,name ,sum(mkt) from table1
    union all
    select officer ,name ,sum(mkt) from table2
```

Comment: Maybe you could explain a bit more what this code does for future readers?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180026.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396