# How to combine records from different tables and run the query using SQL?

Tags: sql, vba, excel, ado

*The original question is unclear so I modify the question and ask again*

original question :[How to combine records from different tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38452390/how-to-combine-records-from-different-tables)

---

There are two worksheets in same workbook that have the same structure-same field names.

for example :

Table 1

```
- Officer  name   mkt 
 - s15     peter  15
 - s17     mary   18
 - S32     tom    42
 - S32     tom    89
```

Table 2

```
- Officer  name   mkt 
 - s56     jason  55
 - s31     alex   34
 - S54     gee    45
```

Now I'm using ADO to run the sql in excel-vba.There is no DBMS .I just run and paste on excel work-sheet.

```
select officer ,name ,sum(mkt) from [$table1]
```

Now I want to combine these 2 tables records and select later.

That means:

Table 3

```
- Officer  name   mkt 
 - s15     peter  15
 - s17     mary   18
 - S32     tom    42
 - S32     tom    89
 - s56     jason  55
 - s31     alex   34
 - S54     gee    45
```

Then later make the selection(SQL) .

```
  select officer ,name ,sum(mkt) from [$table3] group by officer
```

**Is it able to perform it in SQL or VBA (i prefer to perform it in SQL Statement )?**

*I prefer to use sth SQL technique to perform it . Something like join table ? But join table only join the columns in different tables.Now I want to join rows *

## update

As people suggest to use `union all` 
i try

```
SELECT office, name, sum(mkt)
FROM(
    SELECT *
    FROM [$table1]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT *
    FROM [$table2]
) as table3
GROUP BY officer
```

it occurs `from-clause error`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this may help you

```
SELECT Officer, name, sum(mkt) FROM (
SELECT Officer,name,mkt FROM [$table1]
UNION ALL
 SELECT  Officer,name,mkt 
    FROM [$table2]
    ) as table3
GROUP BY officer,name
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use temptable or CTE(common table expression) or using by JOINs

Temptable:

```
create table #tablename(columname datatype)
```

CTE:

```
with ctename as (select columns from tablename)
```

JOINS:

```
select columnname 
       from table1 t1
       left join table2 t2 on t1.commonecolumnname=t2.commoncolumnname
```