# Combining identically structured tables into a single PivotTable

Tags: excel, pivot-table, pivot-chart

Good Evening,

I have a number of workbooks each containing a table of identical structure. The columns are as follows:

`[ID]` `[Contract]` `[Team]` `[Type]` `[Jan Hrs]` `[Feb Hrs]` `[Mar Hrs]` etc etc.

Each of the tables holds an undefined number of rows. Dependent on the team and/or contract this may be 10s or 1000s of rows.

I would like to combine these into a single data source to then create a number of PivotTables and PivotCharts from.

Is anyone able to provide some help?

Comment: Is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9923385/combine-2-excel-tables-into-one-appending-the-data) helpful?

Comment: It is interesting, but doesn't quite do what I want. I'm really looking for a way to maintain a datasource without VBA - it might not be possible.