# Google Sheets - sync row deletions across multiple tabs?

Tags: excel, tabs, drive

Using Google Sheets to keep track of product data. Data is split into multiple tabs, in order to keep it organized & make it easier for different team members to update different aspects of products (1 person does pricing, another worker in warehouse measures the product & packaging dimensions, the webmaster photoshops the product images, etc).

There is a "master" list of product SKUs in the 1st tab.
All other tabs start with the same list of SKUs, kept in sync by the IMPORTRANGE() function.

Here's the problem: deleting a row from the 1st tab does NOT delete the entire row from other tabs. It ONLY deletes the SKU in the 1st column - causing the SKU list to shift and mismatch with the rest of the product info.

How can I make row deletions & additions to synchronize across multiple tabs in the same sheet? (In other words, I want it to work as if it was all in 1 tab).

Screenshot: [image]

Comment: Have a look at [Combine 2 Excel tables into one appending the data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9923385/combine-2-excel-tables-into-one-appending-the-data).

Comment: Just did, and now I'm even more confused... should I be focusing on the IF/COUNTA trick ( ... =IF(ROW()<=COUNTA(Sheet1!A:A),"Sheet1",IF(ROW()<COUNTA(Sheet1:Sheet2!A:A),"Sheet2","")) ... ), or indexing the rows with "=IF( INDIRECT("Table3[RowId]")<=ROWS(Table1)
    ,INDEX(Table1[column1],INDIRECT("Table3[RowId]"))
    ,INDEX(Table2[Column1],INDIRECT("Table3[RowId]")-ROWS(Table1)))" ???

#totallylostnow