# Combine 5 tables from seperate worksheets excel

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I have 5 tables with the same structure on separate worksheets, which i want to combine into one aggregated table on a seperate worksheet.

The individual tables update regularly so the aggregated results need to update.

I found a MergeRange UDF (below) which works for combining columns. Ideally I want to extend this to merge the entire rows (keeping the correct order from each table).

I have searched everywhere for this - I believe it can be done using MS powerquery but I am a mac user so a simple UDF would be amazing.

Thanks in advance for any help.

```
 Option Explicit

    Function MergeRanges(ParamArray arguments() As Variant) As Variant()
    Dim cell As Range, temp() As Variant, argument As Variant
    Dim iRows As Integer, i As Integer
    ReDim temp(0)

    For Each argument In arguments
      For Each cell In argument
        If cell <> "" Then
          temp(UBound(temp)) = cell
          ReDim Preserve temp(UBound(temp) + 1)
        End If
      Next cell
    Next argument

    ReDim Preserve temp(UBound(temp) - 1)
    iRows = Range(Application.Caller.Address).Rows.Count
    For i = UBound(temp) To iRows
      ReDim Preserve temp(UBound(temp) + 1)
      temp(UBound(temp)) = ""
    Next i

    MergeRanges = Application.Transpose(temp)

    End Function
```

Comment: Without having tested your code that combine columns, have you tried wrapping it in:
    for each row ....

Comment: I should add I'm a VBA beginner so haven't tried that. Would it be inserted before 'For each argument'?

Comment: If you are indeed new to VBA you should really start with using the language itself. Can you write a for-next loop? Can you write a do-while loop? Can you handle errors (without the newbie error On Error Resume Next) ?

Comment: No I can't do any of that

Comment: Well, I'm sure you understand the need for a basic knowledge of the tool you indend to use.

Comment: It seems to be a pretty easy job with Power Query. Google "Power Query to combine tables from multiple files" and you will get enough resources to go through. And if you do this through Power Query, after the tables are changed or modified, all you need to refresh the Query to update the merged file. That's it.

Comment: What you want is called "Consolidating data" (in multiple worksheets). [Here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Consolidate-data-in-multiple-worksheets-007ce8f4-2fae-4fea-9ee5-a0b2c9e36d9b "Here") you can find how to do this. No VBA needed, just regular Excel functionality. If the link gets broken, just search for "consolidating worksheets".

Comment: @ffonz - Thanks - I tried consolidating data but I don't want to sum the rows, just want them  aggregated (more like a index/match) all in one place.

I tried [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9923385/combine-2-excel-tables-into-one-appending-the-data):

=IFERROR(INDEX(Table1, ROW([@[no.]])-ROW(Table3[#Headers]),COLUMN(A:A)), INDEX(Table2, ROW([@[no.]])-ROW(Table3[#Headers])-ROWS(Table1),COLUMN(A:A)))

[@[no.]] - gave me a reference error

Comment: @sktneer - Thanks - I'm using a Mac so don't have power query available.