# How to combine three excel tabel without access and vb?

Tags: excel, merge

Is there a way to combine three excel table ıf I dont have access and If I dont want to use vb.

Let s assume that we have different exam results of students.What I want to find, The students who have answered every questıon in every exam. In this case the answer is Bob. But If the are three excel shet how can cobıne them and fınd the rıght student?

```
Table1

Name     id   q1       q2     q3        q4
Adam     1     a      null     b         c
Sally    2     b       c      null       d
Bob      3     c       b       a         c
Jack     4     a       b       b         d  
Marc     5     b       c       a         d


TABLE 2

Name   id     q5      q6      q7      q8
Adam    1     null     b       c      a
John    6     b        c      null    d
Bob     3     a        b      a       c
Jack    4     c        b      c       d  


TABLE 3

Name     id     q5      q6      q7     q8
Adam     1     null     b       c      a
Sally    6     b        c      null    d
Bob      3     a        b       a      c
Jack     4     c        b       c      d  
Leonard  7     c        a      null    a
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Combine 2 Excel tables into one appending the data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9923385/combine-2-excel-tables-into-one-appending-the-data).

Comment: Didn't Jack answer *'every questıon in every exam'* as well as Bob?