# Concat tables in different excel worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

## Question

I'm trying to do something that may be very simple using Excel but I can't find how to do it.

I have several worksheets, each one contains a single table. To give you an example, here are two of my worksheets :

[image]
*First worksheet. Please note that lines are green.*
*Some data. Without 's', sorry :-)*

[image]
*Second one. Lines are grey but cells can be red. Headers are NOT the same*

I would like to :

- merge those tables into another worksheet
- keep style formatting (line color, etc)
- when I update a table, the merged one should update too (may be a macro)

Here is a possible output :

[image]

**Note that same headers are correctly merged.**

Can I do this with Excel ? I know that I can do a query (UNION ALL) but doing this doesn't preserve style formatting.

## Edit 1

I've tried to build the table using microsoft queries. Here is my query :

```
SELECT * FROM `C:\Users\cflodrops\Downloads\comptes.xlsx`.`Purchases$` `Purchases$`  
UNION ALL  
SELECT * FROM `C:\Users\cflodrops\Downloads\comptes.xlsx`.`Sales$` `Sales$`
UNION ALL  
SELECT * FROM `C:\Users\cflodrops\Downloads\comptes.xlsx`.`Trades$` `Trades$`
UNION ALL  
SELECT * FROM `C:\Users\cflodrops\Downloads\comptes.xlsx`.`Transfers$` `Transfers$`
```

This request works great, here is the result :

[image]

But I still have issues :

- style formatting is incorrect (background colors and numbers format)
- datas are not synchronized between arrays. It's not an issue, I can create a macro to execute the request whenever I click on a button.

Comment: What i am not sure about is if this is a merge or an append of sorts? You have different columns so not sure how UNION ALL would work without adding in the same column names to each table. I think if  this were an append operation and there were matching headers and numbers of rows you could have a helper column which identifies which table the original row came from then apply conditional formatting to the merged table with an IF statement that applies the orginal source formatting depending on the helper column value?

Comment: And were it a merge, i guess you might look at using the header to identify which table the column came from, and use that to apply the right formatting.What i would then be unsure of is how to do this without VBA. Also, the JOIN type would need to be determined. Unsure, if one can override conditional formatting of powerquery table merges.

Comment: Your question is too broad.  You need to clarify the relationship between the  tables and more importantly some code demonstrating the effort that you have put in to solve the problem yourself.  You should worry about the data first then take care of the formatting.

Comment: why don't you record a macro to add "Destination" column into Worksheet1 after Total, then add "Price" column into Worksheet2 after Amount. Then continue the macro with copy and paste with source formating from Worksheet1 and Worksheet2 to NEW Worksheet3. And also record a macro to clear all data in Worksheet3 each time before running the first macro. And also another macro to remove "Destination" and "Price" column from Worksheet1 and 2 after first macro at the end (after Worksheet 3 is populated).

Comment: On one hand, it would be good if you tried something so others can follow up. On the other hand, the merging operation seems to be ill-defined. You should specify what is the result you want to get for the various possible combinations of coinciding/not coinciding values in rows/columns.

Comment: the two tables in your images at the top don't have the same columns - Union All (in TSQL at least, so i assume for VBA SQL operations) requires the same number of columns (also you want them to match up) so how is your query working? If there are matching columns output them with a helper field that indicates source table, apply conditional formatting to the recordset output using this helper column? As per my first comment, this is not a merge but an append.

Comment: Doesn't [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9923385/combine-2-excel-tables-into-one-appending-the-data) do 90% of your tasks with an obvious place to code the remainder?

Comment: I was going to say make a temp table with empty columns inserted on a temp worksheet sheet to ensure proper col alignment prior to merge.  Destroy temps post merge.  This can be done without tables and all in VBA/worksheet but you lose some of the header functionality that comes easily with tables.

Answer (score 1):

you have a few problems...union can work. Assuming union path from your first edit.

Add placeholder columns on both sheets to allow proper union, OR force placeholders columns in with your t-sql queries.

Add columns to each sheet representing the source OR add these in with your t-sql queries. e.g. 'Sheet1'

On your unioned sheet with the results, add conditional formatting, where the row with the cell of the source type is evaluated, then the entire row is formatted as necessary. e.g. cell A2 has 'Sheet1', then row A is colored green.

Answer (score 1):

If i understand you well, you want to:

1. copy data preserving formatting from existing sheets and put them into another sheet (new or existing; let's call it "merged data"),
2. keep one-way synchronization betweem source sheets and "merged sheet", which means when source sheet is changing, a "merged sheet" changes too.

The answer for both issues is YES depending on a way you choose to merge/synchronize/display data...

**Method #1** - using copy & paste data one below another

This method will preserve formatting, but there's no chance to update destination table (sheet) when source data have been changed. You'll need to create it every time you want to see merged data.

**Method #2** - using [Range.CopyFromRecordset method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-copyfromrecordset-method-excel)  together with `UNION` statement

If you want to use this method, you have to change your data set into model of [relational database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database). There's no chance for preserving source formatting, but "merged sheet" may be quickly reloaded (a'ka updated).

Both methods of copying data between sheets you'll find here: [Copy Data Between Excel Sheets using VBA](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1187802/Copy-Data-Between-Excel-Sheets-using-VBA), but this tip does not provide information about copying data within its originall format. So, i decided to clarify how to achieve that and show/provide code which create destination sheet with merged data.

In my example i have 3 sheets. First and second sheet is used as source of data and the 3. one is used to display merged data. Only 3 columns (A-C) contain data, so ranges to copy are hard-coded.

```
Option Explicit

'method #1
Private Sub CopyWithFormatting(srcSh As Worksheet, dstSh As Worksheet, Optional sCol As String = "A")
Dim e1 As Long, e2 As Long

On Error GoTo Err_CopyWithFormatting
'last row in src and dst sheet
e1 = srcSh.Range(sCol & srcSh.Rows.Count - 1).End(xlUp).Row
e2 = dstSh.Range(sCol & dstSh.Rows.Count - 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
'do not refresh screen
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'copy defined range
srcSh.Range("A2:C" & e1).Copy
'paste below existing data
With dstSh.Range("A" & e2)
    .PasteSpecial xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme
    .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
    .PasteSpecial xlPasteValidation
End With

Exit_CopyWithFormatting:
    On Error Resume Next
    'restore default settings
    With Application
        .CutCopyMode = False
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With
    Exit Sub

Err_CopyWithFormatting:
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbExclamation, "Err no. " & Err.Number
    Resume Exit_CopyWithFormatting

End Sub
```

How to use it?

```
Sub TestMethod1()
Dim CopiedSheet As Worksheet, DestSheet As Worksheet

'as i mentioned -> 3. sheet is used to merge data 
'you can change it by using sheet's name or its index
Set DestSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(3)

'copy data from sheets into destination sheet
For Each CopiedSheet In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    'ignore destination sheet
    If CopiedSheet Is DestSheet Then GoTo SkipNext
    CopyWithFormatting CopiedSheet, DestSheet
SkipNext:
Next

End Sub
```

**Finall note:**  Feel free to change above code to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

In the third sheet I would have a macro in the Activate event, that pulls the data from from the first two sheets. I would add a hidden column in the third sheet that contains to originating sheet. In your conditional formatting for the third sheet you would need to base your formatting on the value in the hidden column. I can post a sample to clarify if you wish.

EDIT: Added sample

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Dim Sheet1 As Worksheet
    Dim Sheet2 As Worksheet
    Dim Sheet3 As Worksheet
    Set Sheet1 = Worksheets(1)
    Set Sheet2 = Worksheets(2)
    Set Sheet3 = Worksheets(3)
    Sheet1.Range("A2:D101").Copy
    Sheet3.Cells(2, 1).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Sheet2.Range("A2:D101").Copy
    Sheet3.Cells(102, 1).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Sheet3.Cells(1, 1).Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range _
        ("A1:A201"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
        xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3").AutoFilter.Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

Here is an example file.
[ConcatSheets Example.xlsm](https://www.dropbox.com/s/55o4yz1wbvi1lu5/ConcatSheets%20Example.xlsm?raw=1)