# Adding two ranges from different worksheets into a table

Tags: excel, vba

I have two ranges set in two different variables. Trying to insert one into the tables, then the other range below it. Before the insert I need it to delete the data body of the table (not deleting the table). Then I need to insert my ranges.

Issues currently having:

1. Getting error method 'Delete of object '_worksheet failed sometimes
   on first run when deleting sheets if they already exists. Error
   doesn't seem to occur on second run.
2. Copying NewData to table only inserts the first row of rng1. I need
   to whole range copied to table, excluding rows where value is "N" in
   column A. How do I make it so entire range is copied into table?

   ```
   Option Explicit

   Sub AddDataRow(tableName As String, NewData As Range)
   Dim sheet As Worksheet
   Dim table As ListObject
   Dim col As Integer
   Dim lastRow As Range


   Set sheet = Range(tableName).Parent
   Set table = sheet.ListObjects.Item(tableName)

   'First check if the last table row is empty; if not, add a row
   If table.ListRows.Count > 0 Then
       Set lastRow = table.ListRows(table.ListRows.Count).Range
       If Application.CountBlank(lastRow) < lastRow.Columns.Count Then
           table.ListRows.Add
       End If
   End If

   'Copy NewData to new table record
   Set lastRow = table.ListRows(table.ListRows.Count).Range
   lastRow.Value = NewData.Value
   End Sub


   Sub CopyToDataset()
   Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   Application.DisplayAlerts = False

   Dim ws1 As Worksheet
   Dim ws2 As Worksheet
   Dim destWkb As Workbook
   Dim sh As Worksheet
   Dim destSh As Worksheet
   Dim destSh1 As Worksheet
   Dim destSh2 As Worksheet
   Dim cell As Range, rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range, row As Range
   Dim copyRng As Range
   Dim LastRowDestSh1 As Long
   Dim LastRowDestSh2 As Long
   Dim LastRowDestSh As Long
   Dim myTable As ListObject
   Dim oNewRow As ListRow

   'set source variables
   Const startRow As Long = 6
   Set ws1 = Sheet1 'worksheet "A Jobs"
   Set ws2 = Sheet2 'worksheet "ACC Job Schedule"
   Set destWkb = Workbooks("Job Income Summary Export.xlsm")
   Set destSh = destWkb.Worksheets("Dataset")

   'delete worksheets if they already exists in destination workbook
   For Each sh In destWkb.Worksheets
       If (sh.Name = ws1.Name Or sh.Name = ws2.Name) And sh.Name <> destSh.Name _
       Then
           sh.Delete  '**getting error method 'Delete of object '_worksheet failed sometimes on first run
       End If
   Next sh

   'copy source worksheets into destination workbook
   ws1.Copy After:=destWkb.Sheets(destWkb.Sheets.Count)
   ws2.Copy After:=destWkb.Sheets(destWkb.Sheets.Count)

   'destination workbook set variables
   Set destSh1 = destWkb.Worksheets("A JOBS")
   Set destSh2 = destWkb.Worksheets("ACC Job Schedule")
   Set myTable = destSh.ListObjects("desttbl")
   'Set oNewRow = myTable.ListRows.Add(AlwaysInsert:=True)

   'Find the last non-blank cell in column A(1)
   LastRowDestSh1 = destSh1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row
   Debug.Print (LastRowDestSh1) 'last row is 406
   LastRowDestSh2 = destSh2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row
   Debug.Print (LastRowDestSh2) 'last row is 182
   LastRowDestSh = lastRow(destSh)
   Debug.Print (LastRowDestSh) 'last row is 1

   Set rng1 = destSh1.Range("A7:AD7", destSh1.Cells(LastRowDestSh1, 32))
   Set rng2 = destSh2.Range("A7:AD7", destSh2.Cells(LastRowDestSh2, 32))

   'Clear table contents
   With myTable.DataBodyRange
       On Error Resume Next
       .Rows(1).ClearContents
       .Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, _
       .Columns.Count).Rows.Delete
       On Error GoTo 0
   End With

   'Copy NewData[rng1 and rng2] NewData to new table record
   'If UCase(rng1.Cells(cell.row, "A").Value) = "Y"


           AddDataRow "desttbl", [rng1] 'only first row is copying to table.


   Application.GoTo destSh.Cells(2, 1)

   Application.ScreenUpdating = True
   Application.DisplayAlerts = True
   End Sub
   ```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9923385/combine-2-excel-tables-into-one-appending-the-data

Comment: Edit for clearing the content: `With myTable.DataBodyRange
        On Error Resume Next
        .Rows(1).ClearContents
        .Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, _
        .Columns.Count).Rows.Delete
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With`

Comment: Next I'm trying to figure out how to grab rows on two different worksheets that if they match a value in column A, then it gets inserted into the databodyrange of myTable.

Comment: "Next" ...sounds like a new question.

Comment: How can I grab rows on two different worksheets then insert into the data body of my table?

Comment: @jeeped I updated my code, with the area I'm still having trouble in. Can I get some help with solving the last piece? Thanks.