# Auto expand Excel table with macro

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel document which pulls data from an Access database.
From here, the data is summarised in a Pivot Table.
It is then pulled into another table which makes it easier to read and filter.

The last table is formatted as a table and formulas are in place.
Depending on the data in the database, this table can reduce or expand the number of rows when refreshed.

When I run the macro to refresh the data and tables, I want to be able to automatically resize the table so all of the data is shown, but no extra blank rows appear at the bottom.

So far, I have the following code which looks up the Pivot Table sheet (Pivot) to determine the number of rows to display in the output sheet (Report):

```
Sub ResizeList()
 Dim ws As Worksheet
 Dim ob As ListObject
 Dim Lrow1 As Long

Lrow1 = Sheets("Pivot").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Report")
Set ob = ws.ListObjects("Report_Table")

ob.Resize ob.Range.Resize(Lrow1)

End Sub
```

However, it only removes the table formatting (not the data) from the extra rows at the bottom when the table reduces in size.
Also, I get too many rows in the Report Table because of the header and total rows in the pivot.

Can someone help?

Comment: You should be interested in [Combine 2 Excel tables into one appending the data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9923385/combine-2-excel-tables-into-one-appending-the-data/32680703#32680703).

Comment: Thanks. I couldn't get that to work correctly. I don't think it relates to my situation enough. I did kind of resolve it with the below where I essentially calculate the rows then remove one. It seems to work, although may be more complex than it needs to be.

`Worksheets("Report").Rows("3:" & Rows.Count).Delete

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim ob As ListObject
Dim Lrow1 As Long
iTBL3rws = -1

Lrow1 = iTBL3rws + Sheets("Pivot").Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Report")
Set ob = ws.ListObjects("Table3")

ob.Resize ob.Range.Resize(Lrow1)

End Sub`