# Dynamically combine two sheets into one

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a similar question to this one: [Combine 2 Excel tables into one appending the data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9923385/combine-2-excel-tables-into-one-appending-the-data/32680703#32680703)

If I have the following 2 worksheets:

[image]

[image]

I want to have a third sheet that looks like:

[image]

How do I create the third worksheet from the original two worksheets? If I add a row to one of the first two worksheets, would the third worksheet automatically update?

Comment: does the row order matter?

Comment: Ideally, I'd like to be able to sort the third worksheet (i.e., sort 'Value' from lowest to highest). It's more important that the information in each row stay together.

Comment: This is easy to do with Power Query (Get & Transform). This method will convert the columns in the original two worksheets into tables. Is that a problem for you?

Comment: Thanks @ScottHoltzman for giving constructive feedback. I have made my question more specific and will go through the resources you provided. (For reference, my original post ended with the question "Is there a way to combine these and have it dynamically update?")

Comment: @MarcoVos I would be happy to use tables as long as two criteria were met. 1) I need to be able to add rows to the original two worksheets and have those changes propogate into the tables. 2) I need the combined third table to populate a worksheet. I'm happy to have the tables all live in some fourth worksheet, as long as I can meet those requirements.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Execute the following procedure for both sheets.

1. Select a value in one of the columns.
2. Goto the Data tab and select `From Table` in the Get and Transform group. Click OK.
3. In the Query Editor select `Close & Load to` from the dropdown menu Close & Load on the Home tab. In the Load To dialogbox select `Only Create Connection` and click Load.

After doing this for both sheets, you should now see the following two queries in the Workbook Queries pane.

[image]

4. Right-click on the Table1 query and select Append. Select Table2 in the bottom dropdown box. Click OK.
5. In the Query Editor click Close & Load (the icon, not the dropdown menu).

You now have the table you wanted. After adding rows to Table1 and/or Table2, the new table Append1 will update when you click the Refresh button on the Data-tab.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Its fantastic, if you have even once run a macro, else you can try first time.

1. On top row click on >> developer
2. On extreme left on top click on >> visual basic
3. Right Click on file name on left top column >>insert module
4. Paste the following code, save and run (play green triangle).

**For combining multiple excel files in one excel files different tabs**

```
Sub mergeExcelFiles()
    'Merges all files in a folder to a main file.
    
    'Define variables:
    Dim numberOfFilesChosen, i As Integer
    Dim tempFileDialog As fileDialog
    Dim mainWorkbook, sourceWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim tempWorkSheet As Worksheet
    
    Set mainWorkbook = Application.ActiveWorkbook
    Set tempFileDialog = Application.fileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    
    'Allow the user to select multiple workbooks
    tempFileDialog.AllowMultiSelect = True
    
    numberOfFilesChosen = tempFileDialog.Show
    
    'Loop through all selected workbooks
    For i = 1 To tempFileDialog.SelectedItems.Count
        
        'Open each workbook
        Workbooks.Open tempFileDialog.SelectedItems(i)
        
        Set sourceWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook
        
        'Copy each worksheet to the end of the main workbook
        For Each tempWorkSheet In sourceWorkbook.Worksheets
            tempWorkSheet.Copy after:=mainWorkbook.Sheets(mainWorkbook.Worksheets.Count)
        Next tempWorkSheet
        
        'Close the source workbook
        sourceWorkbook.Close
    Next i
    
End Sub
```

*Source* https://professor-excel.com/merge-sheets/

**For Merging different tabs in one tab of same excel file**

```
Sub mergeExcelTabs()
'UpdatebyExtendoffice20180205
    Dim I As Long
    Dim xRg As Range
    On Error Resume Next
    Worksheets.Add Sheets(1)
    ActiveSheet.Name = "Combined"
   For I = 2 To Sheets.Count
        Set xRg = Sheets(1).UsedRange
        If I > 2 Then
            Set xRg = Sheets(1).Cells(xRg.Rows.Count + 1, 1)
        End If
        Sheets(I).Activate
        ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Copy xRg
    Next
End Sub
```

*Source* https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/5017-excel-collect-data-from-multiple-sheets.html