# EXCEL - Compare two tables and fill one if matching data

Tags: excel, vba, excel-tables

I would like to get help because I need to improve table data by matching two tables.
Each table are on separated sheet.

The first table (sheet 1) looks like this :

[image]

I have "SIRET number" (id), "Nom du vendeur" (column which need to be filled with data from the second table) and "Raison sociale" (business name)

The second table (sheet 2) looks like this :

[image]

I would like to compare the same column "Raison Sociale" and if the name is the same, add "Nom du vendeur" from second table to first one (the empty column).

Is is possible to get information about How to do that ?

Comment: Research XLOOKUP or INDEX/MATCH or VLOOKUP perhaps.

Comment: Quick search on here and you get: https://stackoverflow.com/q/9923385/4961700

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @BigBen, I used the `RECHERCHEX()` function.
I set the cursor in the cell "Nom du Vendeur" from table 1 and I wrote :

```
=RECHERCHEX(C2;'sheet2'!A16:A13388;'sheet2'!D16:D13388)
```

And it seems to work fine :

[image]

My second column is filled by matching data between table 1 and table 2 with the commune data from column named "Raison sociale"